# How to get Two Arrays of Categories in if/elseif Statement

Tags: magento-1.9, php, if

I need to show different content on the product pages (view.phtml)

Here is the code I have. The first array with the if statement works, it's getting the else if to work that I am having trouble with

```
<?php if(in_array($category->getId(), array(62,63,64,65,66,67,68))): ?>

for prods in these categories

<?php elseif(in_array($category->getId(), array(3,55,56,57,58,59,60))): ?>

 for prods in other categories

 <?php else: ?>

 everything else

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's your actual issue?

Comment: No problem in this code check your `$category->getId()`. code work fine.

Comment: This doesn't work. It only shows the first content for the first array, and then everything else shows for everything else. The second one isn't working.

Comment: What does `var_dump($category->getId());` output? In your second array, you have `58,59.60`, is that intentional? Or did you need `58,59,60`?

Comment: That was a mistake! I corrected it, but still only the first array works.

Comment: @Annie what will you get in `$category->getId()` ?  can you please post your `$category` object?

Comment: <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')-    >getCurrentCategory();?>

Comment: Looks OK so far. Please visit category 3 or 55 or ... and check `var_dump($category->getId())` fits to current category ID.

Comment: Btw ... would be helpful to put some more code to the question :) What you want to achive at the end? What should be content of `for prods in these categories`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have a `.` instead of a `,` in your second array. I think that you are testing it with category number `59` or `60`, which will not make the `in_array($category->getId(), array(3,55,56,57,58,59.60)) === true`.

Try this:

```
<?php if(in_array($category->getId(), array(62,63,64,65,66,67,68))): ?>

    for prods in these categories

<?php elseif(in_array($category->getId(), array(3,55,56,57,58,59,60))): ?>

    for prods in other categories

<?php else: ?>

    everything else

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I changed  59.60 to 59,60, as that was a mistake. But still, only the first array works

Answer (score 0):

The issue is product is assigned to multiple categories. you need to load product first and then get category ids of product.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodId);
$ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
var_dump($ids); //this is category id
```

you will get multiple category ids in Array, then you can compare 2 arrays by using `array_diff()` in your `if..else` condition.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. `<?php
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(prodId);
$ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
var_dump($ids); 
?>
<?php if(in_array($category->getId(), array(62,63,64,65,66,67,68))): ?>

for prods in these categories

<?php elseif(in_array($category->getId(), array(3,55,56,57,58,59,60))): ?>

 for prods in other categories

 <?php else: ?>

 everything else

  <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: what did you get in Category Ids Array?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It is showing nothing

Comment: it shows this for the first one `array(0) { } for prods in these categories`

Comment: did you fetch productId ?? `$prodId`.. inside the load function.  lets chat here. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/63618/abhishek-panchal?tab=access

Comment: I don't have a 20 reputation yet, so it won't let me chat :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost got it. @AbhishekPanchal already pointed you the right direction, you just failed implementing it.

Try this instead:

```
<?php 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodId); 
$id = $_product->getCategoryId();  
?> 
<?php if(in_array($id, array(62,63,64,65,66,67,68))): ?> 
  for prods in these categories 
<?php elseif(in_array($id, array(3,55,56,57,58,59,60))): ?> 
  for prods in other categories 
<?php else: ?> 
  everything else 
<?php endif; ?>
```